Django Tests Throw ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
I haven't found any questions with respect to Django tests and Oracle DB. I am trying to run a test on an existing application, but am running into the table or view doesn't exist error.
I am confused as the test says it is deleting and creating those tables/views.
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Failed (ORA-01543: tablespace 'TEST_EMS12250' already exists)
Got an error creating the test database: ORA-01543: tablespace 'TEST_EMS12250' already exists
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Creating test user...
Failed (ORA-01920: user name 'TEST_PRCQA' conflicts with another user or role name)
Got an error creating the test user: ORA-01920: user name 'TEST_PRCQA' conflicts with another user or role name
Destroying old test user...
Creating test user...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 49, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 72, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 381, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 317, in setup_databases
    self.verbosity, autoclobber=not self.interactive)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 271, in create_test_db
    load_initial_data=False)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 150, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 102, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/scratch/prcbuild/releasejango_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 691, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

This is Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.22.

Not so helpful, but practical, advice is to upgrade.  The latest Django is version 5 so you are very out of date.  This will mean updating Python.  It will also let you use the latest Oracle driver.  See Django 5.0 supports python-oracledb natively.

Yeah, I am trying to build tests to use for each iteration of the upgrade, e.g. test from 1.3 to 1.4, from 1.4 to 1.5, etc.

You can try once with custom configuration. Create a test_oracle.py file with the following contents:
`
    from test_sqlite import *
    DATABASES = {
         'default': {
         'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.oracle',
         'NAME':'localhost:51521/orclpdb1',
         'USER':'scott1',
         'PASSWORD':'tiger',
         'TEST': {
             'USER': 'ff3_user10',
             'TBLSPACE': 'ff3_t10',
             'TBLSPACE_TMP': 'ff3_tbs10',
          },
 },
     'other':{
         'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.oracle',
         'NAME':'localhost:51521/orclpdb1',
         'USER':'scott2',
         'PASSWORD':'tiger',
         'TEST': {
             'USER': 'hh2115_quser1',
             'TBLSPACE': 'hh2_511qtb1',
             'TBLSPACE_TMP': 'h5h1112_qtbs1',
          },
 },
}

`
Grant DBA to the main user(scott1/scott2). Try to pass this configuration with --setting parameter.
Use this command to run -> ./runtests.py --settings=test_oracle --v=2
